# "missing \item" in table despite clear item

Tags: tables, itemize, tabulary

I need to have compact lists in a table environment.
I need the `tabulary` environment for tables and am using `itemize` with options for the lists.

My attempts return the error "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."

The following MWE replicates the issue. I have just updated all packages in MikTeX (on Windows).

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabulary} 
\begin{document} 
  \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{L L}  
  test &  \begin{itemize} \item table item 1 \end{itemize} \\  
  \end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

As was pointed out, the above code works when wrapping the `itemize`-environment in a `minipage` environment.

In order to save time and space, I have created a `compactitemt` environment in order to automatically wrap `itemize` in `minipage`. This initially gave an error, but redefining the environment as in the following code is now working.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tabulary}

\newenvironment{compactitemt}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide=0pt]
    }{ \end{itemize}\end{minipage} }

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{| J | J |} 
        other column & 
            top line 1
            \begin{compactitemt}
                \item table item 1
            \end{compactitemt}
            bottom line 1
        \\ 
    \end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

The end goal is to have evenly spaced `J` columns that contain lists, like such:

[image]

It would have been ideal if, in the above example, the second column would be only as wide as the text inside if the text is so short that there are no line breaks, but I believe I can deal with this by manually using `tabularx` and then the `l` column, when the table is so small that it should be less than a line wide.

[image]

Comment: You should try to simplify your examples, this can be reduced to the following which would greatly help anyone trying to answer `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{L L} 
test & 
\begin{itemize}
\item table item 1
\end{itemize}
\\ 
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}`

Comment: You have used `l` columns which are always single line and can not have lists. using `tabulary` with `l` is anyway wrong, it should be `L` although you get the same error there which could be fixable perhaps in `tabulary` or place the list in a `parbox`

Comment: the document as posted could never have worked, this is not a change in latex.

Comment: I took over your adjustment. 
When searching for the error, I replaced the `L` columns with `l` and did not revert it back for the MWE, but when I reverse it now, the error persists.
I have already attempted to use a minipage environment, and indicated this in the first MWE before the suggested edit, but this is no longer visible in the reduced MWE.

Answer (score 3):

`tabulary` uses hmode to measure how much data is each cell, this means that vertical constructs such as lists do not wor. it locally makes `\[` safe during trials (acting as `$` but nothing else. A very basic modification for itemixe would be as below, but the output isn'tthat great. I woud use a normal `tabular` and choose the width of the `p{...}` column by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\makeatletter
\def\TY@list#1#2{%
  \renewcommand\item[1][]{ }%
  }
\def\TY@tab{%
  \setbox\z@\hbox\bgroup
  \let\[$\let\]$%
% new bit to make itemize safe
  \let\list\TY@list
  \let\enditemize\relax
  \let\endlist\relax
% end change
  \let\equation$\let\endequation$%
    \col@sep\tabcolsep
    \let\d@llarbegin\begingroup\let\d@llarend\endgroup
    \let\@mkpream\TY@mkpream
      \def\multicolumn##1##2##3{\multispan##1\relax}%
    \CT@start\TY@tabarray}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{L L} 
test & 
\begin{itemize}
\item table item 1
\end{itemize}
\\ 
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I surround the list in a minipage environment, which worked.
When I define an environment to include the minipage automatically, the error returns:     ```\newenvironment{compactitemt}{\begin{itemize}[nosep, wide=0pt,
    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
    after ={\end{minipage}} ]   }{ \end{itemize} } ```
Using the ```compactitemt``` as thus defined, is faulty, but using ```itemize``` and surrounding with ```\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}     \end{minipage}``` directly in the table works. Is there an error in the environment?

Comment: yes minipage will work but a minipage is a fixed specified width so you can simply use a `p` column of that width as `tabulary` `L` column can do nothing about the width of a minipage. @Marie.P.

Comment: As suggested, the ```compactitemt``` environment works as defined when I am using a ```p{8cm}``` column of ```tabulary``` instead of ```L```. But my goal is to have multiple columns with compact lists next to each other, and my understanding is that two ```L``` columns next to each other would make latex give them the same width that is in line with the ```\linewidth``` and the width of columns, thus avoiding the need to manually specify widths for every table.

Comment: @Marie.P. Maybe you want `tabularx` instead of `tabulary` and `X`-columns instead of `L`-columns. But maybe you should ask a more clear question specifying your real needs.

Comment: Thank you, I actually need the ```tabulary``` environment due to the ```J``` columns, but this did not survive the initial reductions in the question's MWE, which led to the same error message, but due to a different reason.  I documented the solution in the question.

Comment: why would you need tabulary and J??? I wrote that and I've never used it. Justified text is the default in all standard tables and tabularx. I only had to add J to tabularx to act like X in tabulary or p in a normal tabular. @Marie.P.

Comment: @Marie.P. " I documented the solution in the question" please don't do that, it spoils the question and answer format of the site. If you want to show a solution post a separate answer post. (using a nested minipage inside a tabulary avoids the error but negates everything tabulary does so there really is no point in using tabulary as you show there, just use a normal tabular.